# Stake holder mapping and management

Tags: stakeholders, management

What are some of the ways I can do stake holder mapping and stake holder management ? 
Although at the moment I am not sure what the end objective is, I am keen to understand the same.

Answer (score 3):

On big projects with a multitude of stakeholders, it may be
hard for the project manager to properly cater to all of the stakeholders.
Therefore,  it is a must for the project manager to know who the most influential stakeholders are and who is able to provide support on a project.

Here is the list of typical questions:

- Who will have or require direct/indirect involvement?
- Who has the power to kill the project?
- What is the urgency of the deliverables?
- Who may require more or less information than others?

You should perceive, that not all stakeholders are equal in influence and authority to make decisions in a timely manner. 
Moreover, it is important to keep in mind that stakeholders can change during the life of the project.

Stakeholder mapping is most frequently displayed on a grid, comparing
stakeholders’ power and their level of interest.

[image]

The four cells can be defined as:

**Manage closely**: They are the epicentr of your project. These people can
make or break your project. You must put forth the greatest effort to satisfy
them.

**Keep satisfied**: These people are high-powered, however they are less interested in the project. You must put forth some effort to satisfy
them but not with excessive detail that can lead to total disinterest.
They may not even get involved until the end of the project.

**Keep informed**: These are people with limited power but keen interest in the
project. They can be as an early warning system of approaching problems
and be able to assist with some technical issues. They are the stakeholders who often provide hidden opportunities.

**Monitor only**: This is group of people with limited power. They may not be
interested in the project unless a disaster occurs. Provide them with some
information but not with too much detail so that they will become bored